# Need help converting Integer to Time

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I looked through online solutions for this, none worked for me so I'm posting here. I have separate date and time columns, both stored as integers. I am able to convert the date column to DATE, but not for the Time column. The column value is: `52700`, when using  `TO_TIME(TO_CHAR(OHCRTM))` I get `14:38:20` but it should be `07:27:00`. I've tried various formatting (`TO_TIME(TO_CHAR(OHCRTM),'HH24.MI.SS'`) but I get a 'cannot parse' error. Any idea how I can get the correct time?

Comment: Why should it be 07:27 and not 14:38? After all 52700 seconds are 14 hours and fractions

Comment: I was comparing with our fact table where the data is in proper formats, and there the time is showing as 07:27:00. I didn't think that the time could be wrong in the fact table so didn't think to check.

Comment: Look at my updated answer - it could be reading that hour as HHMISS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

14:38:20 is the right answer, unless you can give us the logic that would make it 07:27:00.

52700 seconds are exactly 14 hours, 38 minutes, and 20 seconds.

[image]

---

Another option to read 52700 would be a time without the colons, ie 05:27:00. To parse it like that the needed SQL is:

```sql
select to_time(52700::string, 'HHMISS');
```

I guess 05 becomes 07 after a timezone conversion then?

Comment: Ok yes it wasn't in milliseconds, the time was just without the HHMISS format. this solution worked! thanks so much!

Comment: its I also looked into the our fact table procedure and realized it was adding 2 hours (PST to CST time zone difference) so that's why i was getting 7:27 instead of 5:27:00.